# Validation rule triggered even with wrong status

Tags: validation-rule

When the status is "Completed" or "Complete" no one should be able to edit a record.

I wrote the following validation rule:

```
AND(OR( AND( NOT(ISCHANGED(Status)),
OR( ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Complete'), 
 ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Completed') ) ), 
 AND( ISCHANGED(Status),
OR( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Complete'), 
 ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Completed')))))
```

But the above rule throws an error even when I'm changing the status picklist to a value other than "Completed" or "Complete".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You could also change the recordtype when status is completed and assign that recordtype to a page layout where all the fields are read only.

Comment: Is there a reason you're checking whether status has changed?  Did you want to prevent any other edits when the status is changed to Complete as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below, when old status is either Complete or Completed, it will not allow you to update the record -

```
AND( 
  OR( 
    ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Complete'), 
    ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Completed') 
  ), 
  NOT( ISNEW() ) 
)
```

Comment: Hi Radhe, it's working in 1 scenario but it's not working other scenarios For eg old status =working and changes to new Status = Complete this scenario it's not working

Comment: Add one more condition for previous value of Working and new value of Complete in OR condition. Like below -
 AND( 
  OR( 
    ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Complete'), 
    ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Completed'),
    AND(ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(Status), 'Working'), ISPICKVAL( Status, 'Complete')) 
  ), 
  NOT( ISNEW() ) 
)